# Azure AD user replication to onsite AD server

Tags: active-directory, office365, azure, windows-server-2016, azure-activedirectory

I have recently been playing around with Office 365 / Azure AD / Physical (onsite) AD servers. I have managed to create a setup as to where onsite AD users are replicated to the Azure AD portal, and that they can login to Office 365 with credentials create by the onsite AD.

Is it possible to setup my environment so that users created in Azure AD are synced / replicated back down to the onsite AD server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice but at this time this is and unplanned feature for the azure team. The only forms of writeback that are supported is password writeback, and device writeback unfortunately.

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-preview#user-writeback

Comment: Thats a shame. Thanks for the answer though,i'll mark your answer.